# Eclipse Plugin Wizard that takes a zipfile and expands it

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, zip

I am attempting to design an Eclipse plugin.  It is going to be an editor and project creator.  For the project creator wizard, I want to know if it were possible to have the wizard create a standard folder (obviously possible), and then also take a zip file from the user and expand its contents into the standard created folder?  The contents would then be modified by the custom editor I am creating.

thanks!

Comment: 'File > Import > General > Projects from Folders or Archive' does something like this so yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out